# Where to begin with managing web servers / business document file management

Tags: backup, network-protocols, system-administration, file-management

I've inherited a couple of web servers - one linux, one windows - with a few sites on them - nothing too essential and I'd like to test out setting up back-ups for the servers to both a local machine and a cloud server, and then also use the cloud server to access business documents and the local machine as a back-up for these business documents.

I'd like to be able to access all data wherever I am via an internet connection. I can imagine it running as follows,

My PC <--> Cloud server - access by desktop VPN or Web UI
My PC <--> Web Servers - via RDP, FTP, Web UI (control panels) or SSH
My PC <--> Local Back-up - via RDP, FTP, SSH or if I'm in the office, Local Network
Web servers --> Local Back-up - nightly via FTP or SSH
Cloud Server --> Local Back-up - nightly via FTP or SSH

Does that make sense? If so, what would everyone recommend for a cloud server and also how best to set up the back-up server?

I have a couple of spare PC's that could serve as local back-up machines - would that work? I'm thinking they'd have to be online 24/7.

Any help or advice given or pointed to would be really appreciated. Trying to understand this stuff to improve my skill set.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think you should explore using [AWS's S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). The better (S)FTP clients can all handle S3 (Cyberduck, Transmit, etc.), the API is friendly if you want to write a script, there is a great [CLI suite](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/)  that you could use in a cron job, and there are quite a few custom solutions to assist with the workflow you describe. [s3tools](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) being one of the better known ones. The web UI is fairly decent as well.

Automating the entire lifecycle like you described would be a fairly simple process. [Here's](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--schedule-commander-on-windows-os.html) one process for windows, [another](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/11/11/duplicity-s3-easy-cheap-encrypted-automated-full-disk-backups-for-your-servers/) general tutorial, [another windows](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/214-automating-amazon-s3-backups-on-a-windows-server/), and a [quick review](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-useful-amazon-s3-backup-tools/) of some other S3 tools.

I personally use a similar workflow with S3/Glacier that's full automated, versions backups, and migrates them to Glacier after a certain timeframe for long-term archival.